# Send Email from Localhost XAMPP OSX

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp

I want to email my localhost with xammp on mac i have wordpress sites with contact fom running as regular php contact fom I want to email so I know everything works and I receive the mail sent via the contact form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: When I was testing using XAMPP on Linux I had it set up so that the email was sent to the desktop. I believe it used a 3rd party tool like this one http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Answer (score 0):

In localhost does not contain smtp server connection so , initially you add the smtp plugin in you site.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this plugin for WordPress to send email from localhost.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: Yes, have already installed and activated different plugins, but can not receive email